# Publicando app na Apple Store

Tags: xcode, appstore

Ao enviar o app para a Apple Store, recebi o e-mail:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

O que exatamente eu preciso fazer?

Obs: O app foi feito com Ionic e usa plugins para camera, firebase e clipboard

Comment: Quando voce cliccou em UPLOAD TO APP STORE, conclui todas as etapas com sucesso? Apareceu um checbox verde e escrito Pronto(ou algo do tipo) em baixo?

Comment: Verifica o email associada a conta de desenvolvedor que subiu o app, as vezes da problema e enviam um email avisando.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira Na mosca! Os e-mails estavam na caixa de spam. Só não entendi muito bem o que eles querem que eu faça. Veja: Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica o email associada a conta de desenvolvedor que subiu o app, as vezes da problema e enviam um email avisando.

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

É bem autoexplicativo, você precisa adicionar no seu plist essa entrada `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, Isso é um texto que é exibido no alert que aparece quando pede alguma permissão, no seu caso é permissão para acessar o galeria de fotos.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explica aqui o por que você esta pedindo essa permissão, e o que vai fazer com as fotos</string>
```